# Matching against a large number of strings containing spaces in pyparsing

Tags: python, performance, parsing, case-insensitive, pyparsing

With [`pyparsing`](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) I need to write a matcher for expressions like

```
a + names + c
```

with

```
a = pp.OneOrMore(pp.Word(pp.alphas))
c = pp.OneOrMore(pp.Word(pp.nums))
```

and `names` matching one of many entries in the string list `names_list`.

The two complications are:

2. The entries in `names_list` **can contain spaces**.
3. The matching **needs to be case-insensitive**.
4. `names_list` is **rather large** (~20000 entries)

I tried

```
names_kw_list = [pp.Keyword(name, caseless=True) for name in names_list ]
names = pp.Or(names_kw_list)
```

This does not work for entries with spaces plus I'm worried that this is not a very performant way to write this.

Any idea to get this working for spaces in entries and maybe make it perform faster?

Comment: This is not a typical parsing approach, btw. Normally, when there is a portion of the input that could match many possible values, then the values themselves are delimited with start/end markers, such as quotation marks, `<>`s, braces, etc. Also, it seems likely that your list of possible values is likely to grow over time, so you will continually have to update your parser to reflect these new values. Using a delimited expression means that your parser will automatically handle changes in the list of valid values. If necessary, add a condition expression for validating the parsed value

Comment: In the underlying use case the name values are not delimited by a marker. Rather the names ***are*** the markers: They are cities in addresses (and per country we have only a surprisingly small number of them: tens of thousands, not more) and they "split" the address in a part before the city and after it.These parts are semantically usually quite different, so it helps for the parser to know whether it parse information before the city or after the city.

Comment: Address parsing is inherently a hard problem. I have taken a stab at a street address parser in the past, but it is probably only a 60-70% solution. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A partial answer:

The spaces problem can be solved with a correct `stopOn` function:

```
def last_occurrence_of(expr):
    return expr + ~pp.FollowedBy(pp.SkipTo(expr))

names_kw_list = [pp.Keyword(word, caseless=True)
                                       for word in names_list ]
names = pp.Or(names_kw_list)("names")
a = pp.OneOrMore(pp.Word(pp.alphas), stopOn=last_occurrence_of(names))("A")
c = pp.OneOrMore(pp.Word(pp.nums))("C")

expr = a + names + c
```

This instructs `a` not to eat into the strings of `names`.

However the performance deteriorates, because now the long list of names is used in a `stopOn` expression.