# Performant matching against a large number of strings in pyparsing

Tags: python, performance, parsing, pyparsing

With [`pyparsing`](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) I want match part of a parse styring against a large list of strings called `names_list`. This list is rather huge (~20000 entries).

I am interested in finding a *fast* way to match against this list. The `pyparsing.Or` expression

```
names = pp.Or([pp.Keyword(name, caseless=True) for name in names_list ])
```

works, but is not very fast.

How can I  improve this? Two sub-questions about this:

1. Is it worthy it to replace the `Or` operator by another operator (if I possibly pre-sort `names_list` by some criterion)?
2. The list expression `names` will turn up in multiple part of a larger expression (e.g. in the normal parsing and additionally in a `stopOn=` expression. In both cases it will match against the same real part in the parsing string. Is there a way to use this to speed up the matching?

*Side note:* This question has [a sister question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41736402/65889). In the sister question I asked about to many things at once - that's why I separated here the (unanswered) part out.

Comment: 1. Use `MatchFirst`.  2. enable packrat parsing.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire Thx! Does enabling MatchFirst means I ahve to sort the list by string length?

Comment: If the expressions in the list were Literals, then that would be necessary. But since they are all Keywords, it is not needed.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire Thanks Paul. However I've tested it and the list *does* need to be sorted, because the names list can contain spaces, and to match `"aaa bbb ccc"` before `"aaa bbb"` I had to sort the list by reverse length

Comment: Yes, I forget that you said there were embedded spaces. Sorting by reverse length is the brute force solution, but you can also get some performance boost if your list is sorted by likelihood of occurrence, and then only reorder by reverse length for those cases that could be ambiguous. AND use `MatchFirst` instead of `Or` so that you exit out as soon as you get a match. But you only have to sort by reverse length in words not characters, since these are `Keywords`. That is, 'New York City' will collide with 'New York' and has to come first in the list, but 'New Yorkshire' won't.